# How could I get a Relative Entity's count using EF6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading

I have a Entity called "**Client**", and another Entity called "**Card**".

A **Client** may have many **Cards**.

My **Client** Entity looks like this:

```cs
public class Client{
    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to show the **Client** data in a DataGrid in WPF, and I want to get **Cards Count** data,so I add a property to **Client** Entity, which like this:

```cs
public class Client{
    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards {get; set;}

    public int CardCount
    {
        return Cards.Count;
    }
}
```

And then I query the data with Linq and Bind to view

```cs
var query = from n in db.Clients select n;
```

When I run the Application, I got a Exception just right on the `return Cards.Count;` line;

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

So how could I correctly get the **cards count**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way simpler method than the other answers here show. Please also  realize that solutions such as

```
var client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Id = someid); //get a client
if (client != null)
{
    cardCount = client.Cards.Count;
}
```

will cause an issue called Select N+1 problem. Read up on it if interested, but in a nutshell, it means the following:

Because you are not only interested in one exact client, but you want to display `N` clients, you need to do one (1) query to get just the clients. Then, by doing the `FirstOrDefault` stuff, you are actually doing one (1) extra db roundtrip to the database per `Client` record, which results in an additional `N * 1 = N` roundtrips. What this means that, if you were to just query the `Clients` without any related data, you could get however many client records you like, in just one query. But by fetching related data to each of them one-by-one, you are doing way too many db roundtrips.

Here is a way to solve this issue, by using joins and projections. You can get all the data you need in a single DB access:

```
using (var context = GetDbContext())
{
    return context.Clients.Select(cli => new YourViewModel
    {
        Name = cli.FullName,
        // Other prop setters go here
        CardCount = cli.Cards.Count
    }).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
```

You might be wondering, what's the difference afterall? Well, here, you are not working with materialized objects, as others call them here, but with a `DbContext`. By applying the proper LINQ operators to it (note, that this works not just with `DbContext`, but also with any `IQueryable` (well obviously not if you call `AsQueryable()` on an already in-memory collection but whatever)), LINQ to Entities can construct a proper SQL to join the tables and project the results and therefore you fetch all required data in one go. Note that LINQ to Entities IS ABLE to translate the `cli.Cards.Count` into a proper SQL `Count` statement.

Comment: there Also a problem here, I use the Client Entity Instance Bind directly to a Datagrid,How do I show the CardsCount Column Data if I don't have a property in my Client Entity

Comment: Simple, you shouldn't do that. You should always implement proper wrappers for your data to have proper control over what is queried and how. This is the only way to have decent control over performance. However, if you don't need to access the props by yourself and the only thing concerned with the results is the `DataGrid`, then you could use an anonymous type and return the results as a *nongeneric* collection, I am pretty sure `DataGrid` can bind to that as well.

Comment: I try it and a Exception occured:The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Indeed, though it is not mandatory; I just put it there to also point out that you should not return unbounded result sets. You can either leave the paging completely if you just want to display all records, or sort on the PK (or, actually anything you like) by default.

Comment: I add OrderBy before the Skip, and the Exception disappear, but come up a different Exception : "At least one argument did not be assigned value" at the query line. If I replace "cli.Cards.Count" to 0 , the Exception disappear, I haven't found the solution yet

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. Are you sure you are using EF **6** ?

Comment: I am Using EF 6.1.3 , My database is MS Access ，Using Nuget package "JetEntityFrameworkProvider 1.2.6" to Connect the Database. Code First.

Comment: I follow the instruction here to create my database:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542(v=vs.113)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count without loading the entities like this:

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) 
{ 
     var client = context.Client.Find(clientId); 

     // Count how many cards the client has  
     var cardsCount = context.Entry(client) 
                      .Collection(b => b.Cards) 
                      .Query() 
                      .Count(); 
}
```

More information [on MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Since he is using a `DataGrid`, I assume he would like to display details of multiple clients, in which case this will cause a select n+1 issue.

Comment: This can be used in a view model and show the cards count there. I don't think it's a good design to have that property in the entity itself.

Comment: Neither is it a good idea to have it in the viewModel. A viewModel shouldn't contain *any* logic by definition. And no matter *where* you do this, the only place you can avoid multiple roundtrips to the database is if you pick this value right along with the other data. Neither placing it inside the entity nor into the viewmodel will prevent select n+1, this is what I am trying to tell you....

Comment: You are right, but this only does a query like this `select count(*) from cards where clientId = @clientId` and returns an `int`. And if you have this in a view model you will only make this query when needed, not every time the entity is used.

Comment: ... this is because a get-only property will not be evaluated by EF and it has no way of figuring out the logic inside it, so it won't be able to construct an SQL to get the count. Neither does it have a way to find out that you will evaluate the same property for multiple returned results. (in other words it cannot batch the `count`s up). Long story short, no matter where you put this logic, the bottom line is that getting this piece of information one-by-one is a bad implementation. Imagine establishing a connection 10k times if you need to get this data for 10k records.

Comment: "this only does a query like this"...

That would work if you only needed this information for 1 record. The thing that I am trying to point out is that since he is using a `DataGrid` he will *inevitably* need it for way more than just 1 record, and this is what causes serious performance issues. If you display 10k records and the requirement is to display the card count in line with the client then you will need this info for each and every record and therefore you will need to do this query for each and every client displayed, one-by-one.

Comment: Since this is getting too long, I will just point you to this answer. You should examine other suggested questions/answers along with it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/97253/4205470

Comment: Yes, you are correct in the scenario of a list of records and your solution is also correct. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score -1):

You get an `ObjectDisposedException` if you do not materialize the retreived query. In the following case, the query gets executed only when you Access the first time the list from `GetNonMaterialized` and not before leaving the method. Fact of this the `db` is disposed because of lost of scope.

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetNonMaterialized()
{
    return from n in db.Clients select n;
}
```

In the following case the query is executed before leaving the method.

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetMaterialized()
{
    return (from n in db.Clients select n).ToList();
}
```

Always be sure that the query is executed `before` exiting the scope of a `ObjectContext`.

If you want to know whether the query is executed and when enalbe Logging of EF.

[How can I turn off Entity Framework 6.1 logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709811/how-can-i-turn-off-entity-framework-6-1-logging/22710121#22710121)

Comment: Where should I place the GetMaterialized method? and how could I use it? I am new to WPF, so please give me more detail. Thank you~

Comment: This will not work. By calling `ToList` you only force the non-lazy properties to be populated, any related, lazily loaded entities or collections of them will *not* be loaded. The only difference between your two code fragments is that with the first one, you are not even able to fetch the nonlazy props if the context is disposed before access, but with the second one, you can at least get the base properties.