# How to log Failed DbCommand as warning instead of error

Tags: c#, exception, entity-framework-core, ilogger

I have a known problem within a query which I would like to log only as a warning. My issue is that every time the error occurs, I get a log entry for "Failed executing DbCommand" as an error then I get another log entry for my warning. Is there a way to ensure the "Failed executing DbCommand" error is only logged as a warning?

Code

```
try
{
    _context.Objects.Add(object);
}
catch(DbUpdateException ex) 
{
    log.Warning("Warning DbUpdate Exception error details:" + ex.Message);
}
```

Log Entry 1 (For this entry there's no additional information besides the query and it is logged as an error)

> Failed executing DbCommand
> INSERT INTO myTable

Log Entry 2

> Warning: DbUpdate exception error details: blah

Comment: Is this Entity Framework (core)? You might be able to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/22709811/1043380 but it might be global rather than per-query/per-context.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes entity framework core, in the example you shared it turns the logging off completely? Is there a way to just make sure entity framework core logs everything as warning or just for this specific error?

Comment: Side note: I don't know what logging framework you are using, but it's usually better to just pass the whole exception object instead of just the message, as you get better logging then.